# How to return first encountered row that matches one of multiple criterias

Tags: sql-server

I'm stuck in my ablilities to return the desired values from my table.

I have the following query

```
--Part 1
SELECT Patient_ID, [Behandlings Dato], Ydelse
FROM  [Gildoj_flow].[dbo].[Sheet1$] t1
WHERE 
t1.Ydelse Like '%AAF21 OKN%'
--Part 2
OR (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM [Gildoj_flow].[dbo].[Sheet1$] t2
            WHERE t2.Ydelse like '%AAF21 OKN%'
            AND t2.[Patient_ID] = t1.[Patient_ID]
            AND t2.[Behandlings Dato] <= t1.[Behandlings Dato]
            )
    )
AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM [Gildoj_flow].[dbo].[Sheet1$] t3
            WHERE t3.Ydelse like '%UXM%' 
            AND t3.[Patient_ID] = t1.[Patient_ID]
            AND t3.[Behandlings Dato] >= t1.[Behandlings Dato]
            )
    )
OR (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM [Gildoj_flow].[dbo].[Sheet1$] t4
            WHERE t4.Ydelse like '%UXU%'  
            AND t4.[Patient_ID] = t1.[Patient_ID]
            AND t4.[Behandlings Dato] >= t1.[Behandlings Dato]
            )
    )
    Order by [Patient_ID], [Behandlings Dato]
```

I then get the following table (Only a snapshot of the complete)

| Patient_ID | Behandlings Dato | Ydelse |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Forløb15358 | 2019-12-02 00:00:00.000 | AAF21 OKN |
| Forløb15358 | 2019-12-12 00:00:00.000 | UXMG25 |
| Forløb15358 | 2019-12-20 00:00:00.000 | BVAA33A |
| Forløb15358 | 2020-01-07 00:00:00.000 | UXUG25 |
| Forløb15358 | 2020-01-07 00:00:00.000 | BLHN01 |
| Forløb15359 | 2019-12-02 00:00:00.000 | AAF21 OKN |
| Forløb15359 | 2020-01-07 00:00:00.000 | UXUG25 |

Which basically is somewhat correct.

But I need it to return, only the "AAF21 OKN" and then the following UXM or UXU based on date.
Like the example below:

| Patient_ID | Behandlings Dato | Ydelse |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Forløb15358 | 2019-12-02 00:00:00.000 | AAF21 OKN |
| Forløb15358 | 2019-12-12 00:00:00.000 | UXMG25 |
| Forløb15359 | 2019-12-02 00:00:00.000 | AAF21 OKN |
| Forløb15359 | 2020-01-07 00:00:00.000 | UXUG25 |

I really hope that someone can help :)
Let me know if I have to elaborate on something or if my question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Are you talking about MySql or SQL-Server??? They are not the same. If It is Sql-Server (as it looks like) why do you tag MySQL??

Comment: SQL Server (I'm using SSMS)

Comment: Considering an object name like `[Gildoj_flow].[dbo].[Sheet1$]` this is clearly SQL Server, *not* MySQL. Please only tag the RDBMS you are really using. Tagging conflicting applications/frameworks/languages makes it harder for the users here to help you as it means we may not know what language any solution should be posted in. It can also attract downvotes, as something which can't be answered due to conflicting information isn't helpful (in my opinion). It can also end up wasting the time of those you ask for help from, if answer in a language that ends up being the "wrong" one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Larnu. It was a mistake and is now corrected